# Pulling project changes automatically from Bitbucket

Tags: android, git, bitbucket, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have two projects: `Proj1` and `Proj2`. I want to include `Proj2` in `Proj1` like a library. Also, `Proj2` is stored on Bitbucket. Is it possible in automatic mode to pull changes of the `Proj2` from Bitbucket before building the main project?

I use the Android Studio and Gradle.

Thanks.

Comment: Mark, are you aware with 'Jenkins' Continuous Integration (CI) tool ?  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin   Hope this will help you.

Comment: You could use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to include Proj2 in Proj1 like a library.